# Display comma separated field names in an alert box using jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm validating for empty text fields and select tags. I'm trying to show an alert box with all the empty field names (comma separated) on form submit using JQuery. Below is my code:

Jquery script:

```
$('#save').click(function(){
    var invalidFields = $('#startdate, #enddate').map(function (i, element) {
        if (element.value == '') {
        return this.id;
        }
    }).get();
alert('Following fields are empty: ' + invalidFields.join(', '));
return false;
});
return true;
```

HTML:

```
<form id="formname">
    <input class="inputbox" id="startdate" name="change_request.start_date" type="text" />
    <input class="inputbox" id="enddate" name="change_request.end_date" type="text" />
    <input class="submitbutton" id="save" type="button" value="Save">
</form>
```

Alert should show something like this:

'The following mandatory fields are not filled in': startdate, enddate

This is the revised code that is currently working but looping with the alert box even when the condition is true.

Comment: You're reinventing the wheel, and because you say you're a newbie to jQuery I assume this isn't deliberate. Look up the multitude of jQuery validation plugins, they're all very easy to use and will do what you're trying to do here

Comment: @scrowler **reinventing the wheel** ..LOL...

Comment: Infact i was sure that i was missing something... I was not able to figure out the way to loop using arrays as against how we do in normal javascript code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code inside your submit handler function,

```
var invalidFields = new Array();
$('#formname input[type=text]').filter(function (i, element) {
    if (this.value == '') {
        invalidFields.push(this.id);
    }
});
alert(invalidFields.join(', ') + ' are empty');
```

Or,

Simplest ,

```
var invalidFields = $('#formname input[type=text]').map(function (i, element) {
    if (element.value == '') {
        return this.id;
    }
}).get();
alert(invalidFields.join(', ') + ' are empty');
```

Comment: I have a small issue now. Im not able to submit the form. It loops in displaying the alert box even when the fields are not empty.. I'm using .submit function and have changed the button type to submit.

Comment: @user3292043 can you post code here..update your question will help you

Comment: $('#save').click(function(){
  var invalidFields = $('#startdate, #enddate').map(function (i, element) {
   if (element.value == '') {
   return this.id;
   }
  }).get();
 alert('Following fields are empty: ' + invalidFields.join(', '));
 return false;
 });
    return true;

Comment: this is the code.. in this when i change click function to submit function and button type to submit it fails to work.. if i use click function then it fails to call submit function while returning true..

Comment: thanks Pilot! u r awesome.. One more question..:-) to make the message user friendly, is it possible to display the textfield label in the alert box than displaying the text field id?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/75a6S/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var invalidFields = new Array();
    var theText = invalidFields.join(', ');
    $('#save').click(function () {
        $('#formname input[type=text]').each(function (n, element) {
            if ($(element).val() == '') {
                theText += '' + $(element).attr('id') + ', ';
            }
        });
        alert("folowing field are empty - " + theText);
        return false
    });
    return true;
});
```